# Realm access from incorrect thread error in recyclerview

Tags: android, multithreading, android-recyclerview, realm

i want to show the result of a realm query in my recycler view, using a Filter.
So I've implemented this code:

```
public class ListAirportFragment extends Fragment
{
Realm realm;
List<AirportR>airports = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_airport, container, false);

    RealmConfiguration defaultConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build();
    realm = Realm.getInstance(defaultConfig);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchview);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


    //final RealmResults<AirportR> airps = realm.where(AirportR.class).findAllAsync();
    final RealmResults<AirportR> airps = realm.where(AirportR.class).findAll();

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    final AirportAdapter adapter = new AirportAdapter(airports,getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction()
    {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<airps.size();i++)
            {
             airports.add(airps.get(i));
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
    });

/*        airps.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<AirportR>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<AirportR> element)
        {
          for (int i = 0; i<element.size();i++)
          {
           airports.add(element.get(i));
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }


        }
    });  */

   searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
   {
       @Override
       public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
       {
           return false;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
       {
           adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
           return true;
       }
   });

   return rootView;
}

}
```

and this is my adapter:

```
public class AirportAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements Filterable
{

private List<AirportR>originalAirports;
private List <AirportR>listAirports;
private Context context;

public AirportAdapter(List<AirportR> airports, Context context)
{
    this.originalAirports = airports;
    this.listAirports = airports;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.airport_show, parent,false);
    AirportClass holder = new AirportClass(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
  AirportR airportR = originalAirports.get(position);

 String country = airportR.getIsoCountry().toLowerCase()+".png";

 int imgID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(country , "drawable", context.getPackageName());

 AirportClass mHolder = (AirportClass)holder;

 mHolder.image.setImageResource(imgID);
 mHolder.country.setText(airportR.getIsoCountry());
 mHolder.name.setText(airportR.getName());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return listAirports.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter()
{
    return new Filter()
    {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
        {
            List<AirportR> filteredResults = null;
            if (constraint.length() == 0)
            {
                filteredResults = originalAirports;
            }
            else
            {
             filteredResults = getFilteredResults(constraint.toString().toLowerCase());
            }

            Log.d("const",String.valueOf(constraint.length()));
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredResults;

            return results;
        }


        protected List<AirportR> getFilteredResults(String constraint)
        {
            List<AirportR> results = new ArrayList<>();

            for (AirportR item : originalAirports)
            {
                if (item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                {
                    results.add(item);
                }
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
        {
            listAirports = (List<AirportR>)results.values;
            AirportAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };
}


private class AirportClass extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
 {
     TextView name, country;
     ImageView image;

    public AirportClass(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);

        name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        country = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
        image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    }
}
}
```

the problem is: when I try to put something to searchView it crashes and, with the debugger, I see this error message:

```
W/Filter: An exception occured during performFiltering()!
      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.
```

What's the problem? Before I've user `findAllAsync()` method to get the result and after I use simple `findAll()` but I get the same error message...does it not the same thread? Or there are other problems in the filter?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you query for airports on the UI thread, and later tries to access these same objects in another thread. This is not allowed.

The method [performFiltering](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html#performFiltering(java.lang.CharSequence)) runs on a worker thread. When it calls `getFilteredResults`, it tries to access a property(`item.getName()`) of a Realm Object that was queried on another thread(UI). As the error says, Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.

If you want to be able to access the objects you queried for in another thread, you might want to get a deep copy of them, so that they are detached from Realm. In your example, after querying for airports, you could use the method [`copyFromRealm()`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#copyFromRealm-java.lang.Iterable-) to get a list of regular Airport objects and use it from thereon.

Comment: @nani can you tell me what change you made in your code. I'm getting the same problem and can't find any solution.